# how to include https to restart service on https ping result

Tags: batch-file, https, jscript

Hi I would like to to a https request on my server.  How can I include https to do get the response?  I want to restart the server if I get a https code result that is not 200. Here is my source code

```
@set @x=0 /*
:: ChkHTTP.cmd
@echo off
setlocal
set "URL=https://localhost:8080/ping.xhtml"
cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" %URL% | find "200"  > nul
echo going to check error
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
echo Web server ok 
) else (
echo Weber server not ok
echo kill task and then restart service
)
JScript */
var x=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
x.setOption(2,13056);
x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0));x.send();
while (x.ReadyState!=4)  {WSH.Sleep(15000)};
WSH.Echo(x.status);
```

It will wait for 15 seconds before it runs.  But it runs forever if its https?

I want to ignore SSL errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont be possible to ignore the SSL Errors due to the fact that it runs on https. Alternative run it on the server with http example: http://localhost